# Chrome extension: send postMessage from iframe to parent window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing Chrome extension in which I have created iframe. I am trying to send a message with `postMessage` and getting a message about protocol mismatching like this:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://* from frame with URL chrome-extension://gbafofmepfbgfgglhfaddmfnmdcddiig/js/content_script/file.html. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'chrome-extension', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'https'. Protocols must match.

Comment: Is the iframe in an actual tab, or is this loaded inside of a chrome-extension:// page?